compact packed expandable multiple tree
See https://github.com/gitx/gitx/blob/master/screenshot-stage.png
The left panel is similar to what I am trying to implement.
I have tried Flex::column and group::Pack.
But it just distributes all trees equally in the available space. And adds scroll bar at each tree level.
I want something like
BRANCHES
 > branch1
 > branch2

REMOTES
 > origin
 > upstream

Where, if I expand the tree, it shifts everything below down. If I close it, it shifts everything back up.
Also, if the content goes beyond the view, a scrollbar should appear, but at the left panel level.
What container should I use for this?

There was a similar discussion on fltk-general if you would like to check out: https://groups.google.com/g/fltkgeneral/c/6srkhNzDdGE

Thanks @mo_al_ I will dig little deeper later, but it seems that might help me on the collapsable sections. But, unlike that, I don't want user to be able to resize it.

I am looking for more of fluid layout. By default the tree occupies only root node worth of space. no empty space between this and the next section. If the user opens the tree and if it is very long, it just expands to take whatever space it needs vertically. No scrollbar inside the tree. The next section moves down so there is no overlap. Hope this explains. Thanks

I have created a gist with example code here:
https://gist.github.com/MoAlyousef/358f7ffa79d3eb8f17de7a3e89b25e23
It uses a Flex column, and handles the expansion inside the tree's callback method.

Why is this question downvoted and closed as not suitable for StackOverflow?
https://github.com/gitx/gitx/blob/master/screenshot-stage.png is the desired behavior.
"I have tried Flex::column and group::Pack.
But it just distributes all trees equally in the available space. And adds scroll bar at each tree level." is the problem.
"I want something like where, if I expand the ... the left panel level." is the explaination of desired behavior.
"What container should I use for this?" is a question for guidance!

Thanks for trying @mo_al_.
But for some reason, I did not get scrollbar even when the tree went out of the view. :(
I am on Mac. Could that be an issue?

@mo_al_ I found group::Scroll, but it seems buggy. If I move the scrollbar, it just vanishes and doesn't come back again.
Anyways, will submit a request on the Google Group.
Seems like stackoverflow can no longer be used for guidance questions.

I have updated the gist to use a scroll and pack. It now shows a scrollbar when there are more elements than the view.

Thanks @mo_al_ Thats exactly what I was looking for. I would If I could accept your answer! Thank you again for taking the time.

@mo_al_ The question is now reopened. Can you please add your gist as the answer. I will accept it as an answer. Thanks

The following code uses an fltk Scroll and a Pack. The Pack collapses when the Tree is collapsed, subsequently the below Pack is shifted upwards. The Scroll should appear only when the Pack expands out of its view:
use fltk::{prelude::*, *};

static COFACTOR: utils::oncelock::Lazy<i32> = utils::oncelock::Lazy::new(|| (app::font_size() as f64 * 2.0) as i32);

fn prep_tree(t: &mut tree::Tree) {
    if let Some(root) = t.next(&t.first().unwrap()) {
        if root.is_open() {
            let elems = root.children();
            t.resize(t.x(), t.y(), t.w(), (elems + 1) * *COFACTOR);
        } else {
            t.set_scrollbar_size(0);
            t.resize(t.x(), t.y(), t.w(), *COFACTOR);
        }
    } else {
        t.resize(t.x(), t.y(), t.w(), *COFACTOR);
    }
    app::redraw();
}

struct MyTree {
    t: tree::Tree,
}

impl MyTree {
    pub fn default() -> Self {
        let mut t = tree::Tree::default();
        t.set_show_root(false);
        t.set_callback(prep_tree);
        Self {
            t
        }
    }
    pub fn end(&mut self) {
        prep_tree(&mut self.t);
    }
}

widget_extends!(MyTree, tree::Tree, t);

fn main() {
    let a = app::App::default().with_scheme(app::Scheme::Gtk);
    let mut win = window::Window::default().with_size(800, 600);
    let mut row = group::Flex::default_fill().row();
    let mut scroll = group::Scroll::default();
    let mut col = group::Pack::default().with_type(group::PackType::Vertical);
    let mut t = MyTree::default();
    t.add("Source Control");
    for i in 1..4 {
        t.add(&format!("Source Control/Repo {}", i));
    }
    t.end();
    let mut t = MyTree::default();
    t.add("Commits");
    for i in 1..30 {
        t.add(&format!("Commits/Commit {}", i));
    }
    t.end();
    let mut t = MyTree::default();
    t.add("Branches");
    t.add("Branches/main");
    t.add("Branches/dev");
    t.end();
    col.end();
    scroll.end();
    scroll.resizable(&col);
    row.fixed(&scroll, 200);
    row.end();
    win.end();
    win.show_with_env_args();
    col.resize(scroll.x(), scroll.y(), scroll.w(), scroll.h());
    a.run().unwrap();
}

